# how to call pointer function in Frida script

Tags: objective-c, macos, frida

I'm debugging a macOS app by Frida.
here is pseudocode

```
            rax = [Herlper cfunc];
            rax = *rax;
            rax = (rax)(0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
            rax = [rax retain];
            r13 = rax;
            r12 = [[r13 dataUsingEncoding:0x4] retain];
```

How do I get r12 results in a script?

Hope you can help, thank you!

i tried using this script

```
var f = new NativeFunction(ptr(ObjC.classes.Herlper.cfunc()).sign(),'pointer',['uint8','uint8','uint8'])
f(0x0,0x0,0x0)
```

but it error:

```
Error: access violation accessing 0x600001931050
    at <eval> (<input>:1)
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly `cfunc` is an ObjC method that returns a point of a C-function? Why do you execute `sign()` on the pointer? That doesn't make sense to me. It would make more sense to me without `.sign()`. Then you define the native method and call it with the three zero arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to remove `.sign()` , but the error was still the same @Robert

Comment: As we are talking about ObjC: Is it possible that the returned value is not a pointer but an `ObjC.Block`? AFAIR callbacks are usually stored as such a block instead of plain pointer in ObjC 8see e.g. https://codeshare.frida.re/@ivan-sincek/ios-touch-id-bypass/) . Is the pointer value still as high as `0x600001931050`? because such a value doesn't look like a pointer (too high) instead it could be handle is used to identify something.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have solved the question. The function of `cfunc` is to return the function stack address

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the question.
script:

```
var stackAddress = ObjC.classes.Herlper.cfunc()
var memoryAddress = Memory.readPointer(stackAddress)
var func = new NativeFunction(memoryAddress,'pointer',['int','int'])
var result = func(0x0,0x0)
Memory.readByteArray(result,100)
```